# Modbus TCP/IP Address to PLC Addess

Tags: tcpclient, modbus, plc, modbus-tcp

[image]

- I want to add 0 between the two four number in the plc address you see in the picture.

*Should I use left shift?*

Can u help me ?

**PLC Address = 404606 --> I want value**

**Plc Address = 440606 --> value shown to me**

Comment: What application is the screenshot from? Modbus registers are 16 bits so range from (physical addresses) 0 to 65535. There are a number of way of writing these addresses; the application you are using appears to use the old Modicon convention which prefixes the register with the command (4 = read holding register). As entering 4605 is likely to provide the needed result (see "When 40001 Really Means 1, or 0 Really Means 1" in [this article](https://www.csimn.com/CSI_pages/Modbus101.html) for more info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good ol' Modbus.  After re-reading your question, I believe you are trying to target Application Address for Holding Register 404606.  The edit control is wanting the decimal wire offset of the Holding Register (e.g. for 40020, you would enter 19).

So, to get HR 404606 for the PLC Address static text, you want to enter **4605** in the **edit control**.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing application layer address with the wire address.  The Modbus FC basically defines the leading digit (0, 1, 3, or 4, i.e. Coils, (Discrete) Inputs, Input Registers, Holding Registers).

So at the application layer, the holding register
4001
40001
400001
all would look "identical" on the wire.  The wire "offset" is 1 less than the application "offset" (i.e. app layer 40001 is offset 0x0000 on the wire).  There is no way to specify the number of application layer digits on the wire.

What we've done is stick with 5 digits, and when the wire offset gets past 9999 (0x270F or more on the wire is 10000 or more at the app level), switch to a 6 digit application layer address, i.e.
49999 (5 digit app layer)
next HR is displayed as
410000 (6 digit app layer)
up to
465536 (65536 offset is 0xFFFF on the wire)

There is no "shifting" necessary at the packet level (if that's what you are thinking).

Comment: Oh , i dont look this answer.So sorry @franji1.Thank u so much for ur supports